# flutter: no refresh indicator when using RefreshIndicator

Tags: flutter, dart, refresh, pull-to-refresh, indicator

I added the RefreshIndicator to my page, but there is no indicator visible when pull to refresh. The code is below:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: LocalGalleryTab(),
    );
  }
}

class LocalGalleryTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LocalGalleryState();
  }
}

class _LocalGalleryState extends State<LocalGalleryTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(child: new Center(
      child: new RefreshIndicator(
        child: Text("Local Gallery"),
        onRefresh: _refreshLocalGallery,
      ),
    ));
  }

  Future<Null> _refreshLocalGallery() async{
    print('refreshing stocks...');

  }
}
```

How to use the RefreshIndicator? The flutter [doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html) does not give much infomation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71999855/15512185 Check this answer. It has solutions for 4 different cases.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to add scroll child inside `RefreshIndicator`
see example below

[image]

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: LocalGalleryTab(),
    );
  }
}

class LocalGalleryTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LocalGalleryState();
  }
}

class _LocalGalleryState extends State<LocalGalleryTab> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
        child: ListView(
          children: List.generate(50,  (f) => Text("Item $f")),
        ),
        onRefresh: _refreshLocalGallery,
      );
  }

  Future<Null> _refreshLocalGallery() async{
    print('refreshing stocks...');

  }
}
```

Comment: its not working on ListView.builder! Any alternatives?

Comment: Just to add to this: The refresh indicator might not work when items occupy height less than the parent height. This is due to since the scrolling isn't allowed when the items occupy less space than parent and refresh Indicator allows refresh only when the child allows scrolling. Check @Paresh Mangukiya's answer

Answer (score 81):

Refresh Indicator by default does not work on a short list so add the following to the ListView.builder

```
physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Comment: This will solve it and is the proper answer. Using this will maintain the proper scrolling physics for each platform.

Answer (score 65):

By design, `RefreshIndicator` works with `ListView`.

But if you want to use `RefreshIndicator` with non-scrollable-widgets, you can wrap your widget into `Stack` with `ListView`:

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {},
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[ListView(), YOUR_CHILD_WIDGET],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your solution is the best.

Comment: this doesn't work for me.

Comment: could you add a sample of the code?

Answer (score 18):

```
RefreshIndicator(
   onRefresh: _onRefresh,
   child:SingleChildScrollView(
   physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   child: ListView(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),

   children: _listData.map((i) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text("Item $i"),
    );
  }).toList(),
 )
)
);
```

Add physics in SingleChildScrollView

Comment: This solution extremely helpful. (+1)

Comment: I just spent several minutes trying to understand why a specific screen should be "refreshable", but not the other, and it turns out, the one that wasn't, didn't scroll. thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution of this after little change from one answer which was already there in current page!
Just need to change position of stack children (main widget first then listview).

updated answer which will work 100%:

```
RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {},
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[YOUR_CHILD_WIDGET, ListView()],
      ),
    ),
```

past answer from above answers:

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {},
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[ListView(), YOUR_CHILD_WIDGET],
  ),
),
```

Comment: If you have UI elements that you need to interact with (ie., `TextButton`) all those won't work with this method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ListView with SinglchildScrollView widget also.

```
    RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () {
         //HERE YOUR FUNCTION TO CALL
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
              ListView(
                physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                 children: []
                )
              ],
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Work for me after using physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), in ListView

Answer (score 2):

The most important is to implement in ListView:

> physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),

because otherwise items which are not covering whole screen are stuck and you cannot move/refresh them.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach by far is to use CustomScrollView with RefreshIndicator. See example below.

```dart
class RefreshDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const RefreshDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () async {
        // Your refresh logic goes here
        await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
        return true;
      },
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          // Wrap your widgets with the SliverToBoxAdapter
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Hello'),
                  Text('World'),
                
                ]
              )
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Non-scrollable list view, **RefreshIndicator** does not work, so you have to wrap your widget with **Stack** for implementing pull down to refresh.

```
RefreshIndicator(
  onRefresh: () {
  // Refresh Functionality 
  },
  child: Stack(
            children: [
              ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              // Your Widget 
            ],
          );
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure that you are not using BouncingScrollPhysics() in Listview as it does not allow to refresh.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34563327)

Answer (score 1):

By using `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` now the list is not being scrolled.

```
SizedBox(                              
  child: RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: searchController.getAllArtist,
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: size.width * 0.02),
      child: ListView.separated(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _scrollController,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if(index<searchController.searchedArtist.length){
            return InkWell(
              onTap: (){
                PersistentNavBarNavigator.pushNewScreen(context,
                    screen: UserPublicProfile(
                      artistID:
                      searchController.searchedArtist[index]['id'].toString()));
              },
              child: artistCard(index: index,),
            );
          }
          else{
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              color: primaryAlizarinColor,));
          }
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          );
        },
        itemCount: searchController.searchedArtist.length+(
          isLastitem.isTrue?0:1)),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

RefreshIndicator works with ListView..

```
RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: () {},
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 1, //just to build the Widget once..
        itemBuilder:(context, index) => //your Widget..
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not working -

```
 RefreshIndicator(
 onRefresh: () {return fetchData(); },
 color: colorPrimary,
 child:  Column( children: [...],)]
```

So finally, I wrap my column with a list view then it works -

```
 RefreshIndicator(
 onRefresh: () {return fetchData(); },
 color: colorPrimary,
 child:  ListView(
         children:[Column( children: [...],)])
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case,
i wanted to use both "BouncingScrollPhysics" and "RefreshIndicator". My ListView lenght was 3. Well, my ListView cannot be scrolling. For this reason my "RefreshIndicator" is not working. I solved this issue with "parent" property:

```
RefreshIndicator(
   onRefresh: () async => await refreshIndicatorFunc(),
       child: 
            SingleChildScrollView(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
                parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              ),
            child: MyListView(),
       ),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

as mentioned above refresh indicator only works with Listview so use it else wrap Listview with Stack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).