# Refresh indicator doesn't work when list doesn't fill the whole page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page the has a list with refresh indicator. When I have many elements in the list (filling the whole view and more, i.e. I can scroll), the refresh indicator works. 
However, when I have only one or two elements in the list (nothing to scroll), then the refresh indicator doesn't work. Is this the expected behaviour? Is there a way to get the indicator to work also for short lists?

I tried wrapping the list view (child of refresh indicator) with a scroll bar but the problem still persists.

```
Future<void> _onRefresh() async {
    _getPeople();
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return new Container(
      child: _items.length == 0
          ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : new RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: _onRefresh,
              child: Scrollbar(
                child: new ListView.builder(
                  controller: controller,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return PeopleCard(
                      People: _items[index],
                      source: 2,
                    );
                  },
                  itemCount: _items.length,
                ),
              )),
    );
  }
```

If the length of the items list is 1 or 2 or any amount that doesn't need scrolling, refresh indicator should also work.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Set the physics to **AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics** just like the below code.

```
new RefreshIndicator(
    key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
    color: Colors.blue,
    onRefresh: (){
        setState(() {
            _future = fetchPosts(http.Client()); 
            _getAvalailableSlots();
        });
    },
    child: ListView.builder(
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            //do something
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: In a situation where your preferred choice of scrollPhysics is  [say] `BouncingScrollPhysics()`, `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` resets the ListView to platform specific scrollPhysics. Is there a way around this?

Comment: In case if it didn't work even after adding the physics property, please verify that you haven't used `shrinkWrap: true`. `shrinkWrap` property should be set to `false` for this to work. It took a while for me to get my head around.

Comment: @OniyaDaniel You can pass`BouncingScrollPhysics()` in the `parent` parameter of `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`

Comment: If you are using `SingleChildScrollView` don't forget to add `clipBehavior: Clip.none` to avoid clipping of the children while scrolling down while using `BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() )` .

Comment: I spent SO LONG creating a custom class for this behaviour - speaks to just a quick google search

Answer (score 33):

***Case 1:***

Use AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() in your Listview or SingleChildScrollView.

```
physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

***Case 2:***

If you want to use other scroll physics, use this way...

```
physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
 parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
),
```

***Case 3:***

Make sure you didn't make shrinkWrap, true. ShrinkWrap has to be false like default.

shrinkWrap: true. ❌

shrinkWrap: false. ✅

```
shrinkWrap: false,
```

***Case 4:***

If you have any custom widgets other than a listview, use stack and listview this way...

```
     RefreshIndicator(
      onRefresh: () async {
        print('refreshing');
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          YourWidget(),
          ListView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
     ),
```

Comment: Very helpful answer, especially the Stack case. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

To use with BouncingScrollPhysics:

```
 RefreshIndicator(
              onRefresh: () async {
              
              },
              child: ListView.builder(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
                      parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text("${index}");
                   }),
```

Comment: This is great because I really need ClampingScrollPhysics, so did this -  physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()), thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To make RefreshIndicator always appear, set `physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()` for the scrollable child like below.

```dart
ListView(
    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: <Widget>[widget.bodyWidget]
)
```

If you still have some errors, the below might help.

- `ListView` widget needs to have height value to be "always" scrollable vertically. So wrap it with `SizedBox` or some other proper widget and set the height.
- How to fix the height? Get the height of viewport using `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` and, if needed, subtract the value of non-scrollable part.
- If you use `SingleChildScrollView` and it's not working with `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`, it is because the child doesn't have height. fix the child's height or just use `ListView`.

To sum up, the following worked for me.

`sizes.bottomNavigationBar` and  `sizes.appBar` are the constant variables I made to customize the appbar and navbar.

```dart
RefreshIndicator(
    onRefresh: widget.onRefresh,
    child: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                sizes.bottomNavigationBar -
                sizes.appBar,
        child: ListView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[widget.bodyWidget]
    )),
)
```

If you're finding any reliability, [Refresh indicator does not show up](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RefreshIndicator-class.html#refresh-indicator-does-not-show-up) part of the official doc would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ListView inside of Column with Expanded.

Try Removing

```
shrinkWrap:true
```