# Flutter: How to combine [AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics] with [ClampingScrollPhysics]?

Tags: flutter, scroll

On iOS, `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics` makes the viewport bounce in case of overscrolling. This effect is not desired. Is there a technique to always allow (over-)scrolling without bouncing back? What I am looking for is pretty much a `ClampingScrollPhysic`s that can always be scrolled.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar need to combine scroll physics, where I needed `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics` to make my list refreshable ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70829858/3525158)) but I also needed `ClampingScrollPhysics` because I had a nested list view ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543135/3525158))

I ended up making it work with the following:

```dart
const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
    .applyTo(const ClampingScrollPhysics()),
```

From the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics/applyTo.html):

> Combines this ScrollPhysics instance with the given physics.
> The returned object uses this instance's physics when it has an opinion, and defers to the given ancestor object's physics when it does not.

Maybe something similar would work in your scenario.

**EDIT**: Actually this did not work, the nested list views stopped scrolling properly.  Will leave this up though in case it inspires someone else

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you want to achieve, but you can provide a parent: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics/parent.html

I use the following with a `RefreshIndicator`:

```dart
physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not the answer**

Thank you @chanban, I was able to use your answer to refresh a list view (pull-to-refresh) and load more items (scrollup), when the list content was not enough. My implementation is below:

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       body: RefreshIndicator(
           key: _refreshIndicatorKey,
           color: Colors.white,
           backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
           strokeWidth: 4.0,
           onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
           child: ListView.builder(
             // physics: const PageScrollPhysics(), // Enable snapping behavior
             physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
                 .applyTo(const BouncingScrollPhysics()),
             shrinkWrap: false,
             controller: _scrollController,
             itemCount: items.length + (_isLoading ? 1 : 0),
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               if (index < items.length) {
                 // Return the regular list item
                 return items[index] as Widget;
               } else {
                 return const Padding(
                   padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                   child: Center(
                     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                   ),
                 );
               }
             },
           )));
 }
```

When there is only one item in the list, it can be refreshed using pull-to-refresh action and paginated by scrolling up.